# SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I am using Azure Databricks (10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)) Standard_L8s with cores.

When executing the below code, getting `SparkContext should only be created and accessed on the driver` error.
If I am using import pandas only it's running fine, but it takes more than 3 hrs. for me, I have billions of records to process.
I have to tune this UDF please help in this.

```
import pyspark.pandas as pd
def getnearest_five_min_slot(valu):
  dataframe = pd.DataFrame([300,600,900,1200,1500,1800,2100,2400,2700,3000,3300,3600], columns = ['value'])
  rslt_df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['value'] >= value]
  rslt_df=rslt_df.sort_values(by=['value'], ascending=[True]).head(1)
  output=int(rslt_df.iat[0,0])
  print('\nResult dataframe :\n', output)
  
  return output
getnearestFiveMinSlot = udf(lambda m: getnearest_five_min_slot(m))

slotValue = [100,500,1100,400,601]
df = spark.createDataFrame(slotValue, IntegerType())
df=df.withColumn("NewValue",getnearestFiveMinSlot("value"))
display(df)
```

Comment: start with using Pandas UDFs

Answer (score 1):

I have added SparkSession to my script, and the error continues.
What is weird in my case is that when I run the code on Databricks's Noteoboks is runs just fine, but when I try to run it in a .py script it raises this error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34715771)

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create the `SparkSession` object and provide an App name to it to start working with Spark in Databricks. It is mandatory pre-requisite.

> `SparkSession` is an entry point to **PySpark** and **creating a `SparkSession`
> instance would be the first statement you would write to program with
> RDD, DataFrame, and Dataset.** SparkSession will be created using
> `SparkSession.builder` builder patterns.

Use below statement at the beginning of your code to create a SparkSession.

```
#importing sparksession
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
#creating a dataframe using spark object by reading csv file
 
#creating a sparksession object and providing appName 
spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("pysparkdf").getOrCreate()
```

To learn more about spark sessions and how you can use it, please refer the third-party article by **NNK** [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-what-is-sparksession/).